# Installing Postgresql 9.6 on AWS - EC2

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

I have to install a specific version of `Postgresql` to my `AWS-EC2` instance. 
I followed the tutorial :[Setting up PostgreSQ](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow/wiki/Setting-up-PostgreSQL).

In the past i did as per the tutorial and it worked perfectly fine. This time, since I need the 9.6 version, I twisted a bit :

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql96 postgresql96-server postgresql96-devel postgresql96-contrib postgresql96-docs
```

the installation worked fine. I am now trying to resume the setup :

```
sudo postgresql-setup initdb
```

and get the following error:

```
$ sudo postgresql-setup initdb
sudo: postgresql-setup: command not found
```

i tried the following as well just for the sake of it.

```
$ sudo postgresql96-setup initdb
sudo: postgresql96-setup: command not found



$ ls -ila /etc/rc.d/init.d
total 264
393352 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Nov  5 08:25 .
393347 drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  4096 Aug 26 18:05 ..
393961 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1729 Mar 27  2017 acpid
394280 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2062 Aug 16  2016 atd
394415 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  3448 Mar  8  2017 auditd
394323 -r-xr-xr-x  1 root root  1362 Mar 30  2017 blk-availability
394399 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    46 Aug 26 18:05 cfn-hup -> /opt/aws/apitools/cfn-init/init/redhat/cfn-hup
393935 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  5160 Feb 28  2014 cgconfig
393936 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  3580 Feb 28  2014 cgred
394243 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  3782 Oct  4  2018 cloud-config
394244 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  3763 Oct  4  2018 cloud-final
394245 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  3855 Oct  4  2018 cloud-init
394246 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  3840 Oct  4  2018 cloud-init-local
394058 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2826 Sep 28  2016 crond
393819 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 25651 Aug 17  2017 functions
393820 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  6037 Aug 17  2017 halt
394186 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1395 Dec 13  2017 hibagent
394131 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2267 Nov 12  2018 hibinit-agent
393401 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  8563 Sep 27  2013 ip6tables
393402 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  8468 Sep 27  2013 iptables
394156 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1955 Oct 29  2018 irqbalance
393821 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   652 Jan 18  2017 killall
394324 -r-xr-xr-x  1 root root  2137 Mar 30  2017 lvm2-lvmetad
394325 -r-xr-xr-x  1 root root  2274 Mar 30  2017 lvm2-lvmpolld
394326 -r-xr-xr-x  1 root root  3045 Mar 30  2017 lvm2-monitor
394211 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2904 Sep 18  2014 mdmonitor
394195 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2200 Jul  2 17:59 messagebus
393822 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4334 Jan 18  2017 netconsole
393823 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  5309 Jan 18  2017 netfs
393824 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  6742 Aug 17  2017 network
394003 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  6703 Oct  8  2015 nfs
394074 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  3526 Oct  8  2015 nfslock
394152 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1926 May  3  2019 ntpd
393919 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2049 May  3  2019 ntpdate
394548 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  7949 Dec  4  2018 postgresql96
394426 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1556 Sep 10  2014 psacct
393778 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2034 Sep 27  2013 quota_nld
393748 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1515 May 17  2016 rdisc
394296 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1816 Aug 17  2017 rngd
393273 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2073 May  9  2018 rpcbind
394082 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2518 Oct  8  2015 rpcgssd
394084 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2305 Oct  8  2015 rpcidmapd
394087 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2464 Oct  8  2015 rpcsvcgssd
393972 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2011 Nov 11  2014 rsyslog
393643 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  2056 Sep 10  2014 saslauthd
394014 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  3702 Aug 17  2016 sendmail
393825 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   647 Jan 18  2017 single
394647 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  4180 Oct 23 23:47 sshd
393639 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1642 Mar 19  2014 udev-post
```

Comment: From [YUM Installation - PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/YUM_Installation), try: `/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb`

Comment: Hi John, I just tried and I get :
$ /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup initdb
-bash: /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/postgresql96-setup: No such file or directory. Should i navigate to a specific directory may be ?

Comment: You'll need to figure out where it got installed and run it from there. That page also suggests doing `service postgresql-9.6 initdb` for Red Hat, which is very similar to Amazon Linux.

Comment: Thing is, I didn t navigate to any folder before running the installation. I connected to my Amazon Linux AMI, and simply ran the command above.

Comment: can you update your question with an `ls -l /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin`?

Comment: ls -l /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin
ls: cannot access /usr/pgsql-9.6/bin: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are high that `Amazon Linux` doesn't fit well with `PostgreSQL 9.6` or need extra undocumented custom installation steps.

To install a specific version of services like `PostgreSQL`, the easiest way and probably the new standard is using `Docker` (and `docker-compose`).

So, (almost) whatever the Linux distribution you are using:

- `sudo yum install docker` then `sudo service docker start` (The extensive doc for [Amazon Linux](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_pv/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html) or [other Linux distributions](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/))
- Then install [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/)
- Find an example of a `docker-compose.yml` file for PostgreSQL, there are many. Just make sure your image parameter is set to `image: "postgres:9.6"`
- `docker-compose up` and you should be all set

Comment: I used this solution and it works super easily and perfectly! Thank you !!!